# Data Wrangling in Python to Create a List

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe in Python below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_3_MNTH_AGO': [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'F', 'F', 0, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_4_MNTH_AGO' : [0, 2, 'F', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_5_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_6_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_7_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_8_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_9_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_10_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2, 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_11_MNTH_AGO' : [4, 3, 2, 'F', 2, 0, 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO' : ['F', 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2]
})

df.head()
```

I want to transform those values (string value: C, F, and Z) into some categories with this condition:
if values in column CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO, CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO, ......., CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO consist:

```
C = -1
F = -2
Z = -3
else value  = value
```

Then I transpose the table to identify Month Since Dlq (MSD).

```
dfT =pd.DataFrame(df.T).reset_index(inplace=False)
dfT
```

**I want to create a list with the name of MSD**. MSD is identified for value if it is *greater than 1* ( value > 1). For example, in index 2 `CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO = C` or after it has changed = -1 which is not greater than 1. Then, check `CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO` is greater than 1? `CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO = 3` is greater than 1. Hence, the `MSD is 2` because it's in `CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO`. Detail flow chart & overview table for identification [image: click here].

The MSD value is between 1 and 12 depends on `i` in `CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_i_MNTH_AGO`, `for i = 1,2,3,...,12`.
**So the final result is a MSD list with 24 value, identified for each index 0 -23.**

Comment: is that all of the code you've tried?

Comment: Yes, it is. But how to change the value of C= -1, F = -2, and Z = -3 to this dataset first, so that I can identify every row that has value > 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it what you are looking for:

```
# From your dataframe
MSD = df.T.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').ge(1).idxmax(axis=0) \
        .str.extract(r'CYC_(\d+)_MNTH', expand=False).astype(int).tolist()

print(MSD)

# Output:
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 6, 2]
```

Comment: Final result that I expected is MSD = [1,1,2,2,2,2,2,10, 2, 2,2,2,7,2,2,2,2,2]. Put the values from the last month that has value > 1. The value storages into the list same as i on CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_i_MNTH_AGO . For example, when CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO = 2, so the MSD is 1 because it is greater than 1.

Comment: @AnwarSanusi. With the expected output is always more clear :). I updated my answer, can you kindly check it please?

Comment: Final result is TRUE. But I couldn't succeed execute from `MSD = df.T.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').gt(1).idxmax(axis=0) \
        .str.extract(r'CYC_(\d+)_MNTH', expand=False).astype(int).tolist()` got an error : **AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!**

Comment: Try to remove `.T` if your dataframe is already transposed like on your image.

Comment: It worked by removed .T. But # My Output : `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 6, 2]` which is wrong. Your output as showed above is the right answer. #Your output `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 6, 2]`. My concern is in index  0  & 1 , with value 2,2, the right answer should be 1,1 as yours.

Comment: Are you sure using the same data? I started from your dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`

Comment: Check this values: `df.iloc[0, [0,1]]`

Comment: this is the output

`1    1`

`Name: CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO, dtype: int64`. Dunno what should I fix from this code?: `MSD = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').gt(1).idxmax(axis=0) \
        .str.extract(r'CYC_(\d+)_MNTH', expand=False).astype(int).tolist()`

Comment: You wrote **greater than 1**. 1 is not greater than 1. change `gt(1)` by `ge(1)` (Greater than or Equals) or `gt(0)`

Comment: Just knew that **gt**  stands for **greater than**.  Thank you very much. Change by ge(1) it works!